# Is there an easy way to find unused entities/ attributes in entities from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have to delete unused entities and attributes inside the entities that are not used currently, as ours is a very old project, there are more than 100 entities, I am finding it very difficult to go by each entity manually,and deleting it.Is there is any tool/script already available to do this automatically?

Comment: I assume that you know which entities and attributes are currently being used, so you can create for each entity a fake record, and then fetch the last record from each entity, then you will know which ones are not used and perform delete action. This applies for attributes as well. I guess this would helpful haha

Comment: This has to be done programatically..??

Comment: You want to write a script right, can get the sqlite DB file and use any script language to create a connection to that DB and perform queries as discussed above